# Convert Windows event log to text or CSV

Tags: powershell, event-log

I'm new here and i have a question. I'm trying to get the original event logs (Application, System, Security) from Windows and export them to a text or CSV file.

Quite easy, you'd think, but with PowerShell I can't get it right.

If I go to the Windows Event Log screen and select save as..:

[image: 1]

Next i choose save as .txt. If i open that file, it looks like this:

[image: 2]

This is exactly what i'm trying to do with powershell, but i can't get it right. Even with my best friend google.nl it is still a problem.
Can somebody help me with this??

Comment: Could you share an excerpt of the code that you've tried so far in the body of the question? It will help SO members better assist.

Comment: We can't explain why your efforts in Powershell don't work, because you didn't include your code. Please do so in the form of a [mre] that can be copied, pasted and run. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: This is the code i use in powershell: $File = "C:\users\remco\Security.txt"; Get-Eventlog Security | Format-Table -autosize  | Out-File $File

There is text missing in the message collum. it's not complete

Answer (score 1):

From the info you provided, I think you're asking for the Export-Csv cmdlet

```
# Set the destination filepath
$appLogsCsvPath = "C:\temp\appLogs.csv"
# grab the first 100 events in the application log
$first100Events = Get-EventLog -LogName Application | 
    Select-Object -First 100

# Export the events to a csv at the previously defined path
# When converting or exporting csv items in PowerShell
# I recommend always including the -NoTypeInformation switch,
# without it, it adds information to the csv that more often than not, messes it up.
$first100Events | 
    Export-Csv -Path $appLogsCsvPath -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture

# Opens the csv
ii $appLogsCsvPath
```

More golfed version

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Select -First 100 | Export-Csv "C:\temp\appLogs.csv" -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Edit: Added the `-UseCulture` switch to Export-Csv to account for locale settings

Comment: tekst file or csv file, It make no sense for me. It should be clear and uncluttered, like the text file above. With all respect, but if i try it your way: 
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Select -First 100 | Export-Csv "C:\temp\appLogs.csv" -NoTypeInformation
It seems like a mass in excel. Or maybe i do something wrong

Comment: That's an excel thing, and how it behaves when opening .csv files. Just expand the width of the columns by double clicking the column border. Each row is a separate event, each column is a property tied to that event.

Comment: Just add switch `-UseCulture` to the Export-Csv command. Apparently the OP simply double-clicks the csv file and his/her locale setting makes Excel use a different separator character than the comma. UseCulture will fix that.

Comment: Good catch @Theo, didn't even think about the locale settings being an issue.

Comment: I think you'd better update the answer and add this, because I'm not quite sure if the OP reads the comments... ;)